# Correcting formatting on TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'bool'

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to code a filter in my df with the following condition:
Keep IF 'Status' is active OR date closed in the last two years.

Here is a sample of what my df looks like:

| ID | Status | Date Closed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Pending - Under Appeal |  |
| 2 | Completed | 2018/04/15 |
| 3 | Archived | 2021/04/15 |
| 4 | Active - WITH IC |  |

Here is the code I used:

```
*#import tools to do datetime stuff*
from datetime import date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

*#create object to ID date two years prior to today*
two_years = date.today() - relativedelta(months=+24) 

*#create object to ID active case types that we need to keep*
active_cases = [
    'Pending - Under Appeal',
    'Active - With Specialist',
    'Active - With IC',
    'Active - Third Party (Non-Appeal)'
    ]

*#Create conditional that removes `non-active cases OR cases closed more than two years ago.*
df1 = [df[df.Status.isin(active_cases)] 
                    | (df['Date Closed'] > two_years)]
```

This code returns the error:
**TypeError**: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'bool'

My research on this typeerror makes me think I have a formatting issue, but I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. If the code works, it should filter out row 2.

Please let me know if there is anything I can do to make my question more clear bc this is my first question on stack overflow. Thanks!

Comment: Try with `or` instead of the pipe `|`.

Comment: Is df['Date Closed'] returning a date? I wonder if you are comparing non similar var types (I cannot remember if python is forgiving in this). Could try Type() to see if you are comparing incompatible vars

Comment: @Joooeey replacing | with or returns this error:
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: Perhaps you just have your brackets mixed up. It's hard to follow what you're trying to do. But moving the square bracket from the next-to-last-line to the last line might solve it.

Comment: @Danielme I believe these are datetime variables. Previously, the Date Closed argument worked. 

I only ran into issues when I had to change the 'Status' argument into a list. Originally, I was only looking for one string (Status = Active), but now I am using a list for many types of Active cases.

Comment: @Joooeey Could you copy/paste that updated code? I can't quite follow which brackets you are talking about and where to place them. Thanks again!

Comment: `df1 = df[df.Status.isin(active_cases) | (df['Date Closed'] > two_years)]`

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the following minor rewrite of your code:

```
# Your example data
df = pd.DataFrame({
 'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4],
 'Status': ['Pending - Under Appeal',
            'Completed',
            'Archived',
            'Active - WITH IC'],
'Date Closed': [np.nan,
                '2018/04/15',
                '2021/04/15',
                np.nan]}
)

# Ensure your date column is parsed as a datetime series
df['Date Closed'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date Closed'])

# Create object to ID active case types that we need to keep
active_cases = [
    'Pending - Under Appeal',
    'Active - With Specialist',
    'Active - With IC',
    'Active - Third Party (Non-Appeal)'
    ]

# Combine boolean conditions with | (pipe) operator
# inside the outermost DataFrame-indexing square brackets
df1 = df[df['Status'].isin(active_cases) | 
        (df['Date Closed'] > df['Date Closed'] - pd.DateOffset(years=2))]

print(df1)

   ID                  Status Date Closed
0   1  Pending - Under Appeal         NaT
1   2               Completed  2018-04-15
2   3                Archived  2021-04-15
```

Comment: Thank you Peter! I am a self-taught beginner, and it is very helpful to see how you formatted the code.